# LoadError no such file when trying to load gems under rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm getting a 'no such file' error when I try to require some gems in a rails console. Strangely, I don't get this error when requiring them in irb.

Thanks in advance.

```
        $ irb
irb(main):001:0> $LOAD_PATH
=> ["/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux"]
        irb(main):002:0> require 'rubygems'
        => true
        irb(main):003:0> require 'image_science'
        => true
        irb(main):004:0> require 'mini_magick'
        => true
        irb(main):005:0> 
        $ rails console
        Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
        irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
        => nil
        irb(main):002:0> require 'image_science'
        LoadError: no such file to load -- image_science
            from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    ...
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
        irb(main):003:0> require 'mini_magick'
        LoadError: no such file to load -- mini_magick
            from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    ...
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
        irb(main):004:0> $LOAD_PATH
        => ["/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.25/vendor/fssm/lib",  "/home/username/appname/lib", "/home/username/appname/vendor", "/home/username/appname/app/models", "/home/username/appname/app/mailers", "/home/username/appname/app/helpers", "/home/username/appname/app/controllers", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.10.1/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.10.1/ext", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/oauth2-0.1.1/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-0.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/haml-3.0.25/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.5.7/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/multipart-post-1.1.0/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.4/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-2.0.9/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.2.15/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.9/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mime-types-1.16/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-0.3.24/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.5.7/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.6.6/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.5.0/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/builder-2.1.2/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/abstract-1.0.0/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/local/lib/site_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/vendor/html-scanner", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/vendor/multimap", "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/vendor/regin"]
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'pg'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'haml'
```

Comment: What does your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: @andrew-marshall I edited the question to add my Gemfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot require gems in Rails that are not in your Gemfile. You have to either include them in your Gemfile, or specify the full path to the gem when requiring, e.g. `require "/full/path/to/gem"`.

This is because of the way Bundler works and overrides your existing load path. If you run `$LOAD_PATH` in the Rails console you'll see that it differs significantly from the one in IRB.

Comment: I also tried it with the gems in the Gemfile. When I do that, the same error message occurs when I run "rails console". You can also see that console's $LOAD_PATH is a superset of irb's.

Comment: I also tried requiring the full path but now it complains of missing dependencies (which are installed, just not on the path it is look for...)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` after putting them in your Gemfile?